# Apache server throw me 502 error when I try to access site with Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, ip, hosts-file, 502-error

I have a little strange case.

I configured two servers in **AWS**: **Develop** and **QA**, the two with **Ubuntu 16.04**, **Apache 2** and **PHP 7.0**. I created a website en Develop, and configured its VirtualHost file. So, in Develop I edit its **/etc/hosts** file to point to itself:

```
127.0.0.1 site.test.com
```

And, in QA, I edit its /etc/hosts file to poinut to **Develop private ip**.

```
172.x.x.x site.test.com
```

And, if I test with **elinks** in Develop and QA, I can acces to the site without problem in both cases.

Now, in my local Windows computer, if I put the **Public IP from Develop Server** in mi chrome, it shows me the **Apache default page**. You know, that page with the text *"It works! This is the default welcome page used to test the correct operation of the Apache2..."*

So, I edited **my local hosts files from my computer**, pointing my site to **Develop Public IP**:

```
x.x.x.x site.test.com
```

But, when I tried to access **site.test.com** in my chrome, it thow me a **HTTP ERROR 502**.

I can acces to Develop server by SSH by its public ip, and I can see the Apache default page, but I can´t see the sites I configured in it. But, internally between the two servers in AWS, I can.

What I am doing wrong? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Would it be a problem if you also posted your virtual host file? It would certainly help identifying the issue.

Comment: You say that you can access them internally in AWS, is that when using the private ip? Does it work with the public ip internally?

Answer (score 0):

A 502 error will be logged with more specific information in your apache error log. Perhaps looking at it will provide some relevant information that will help you figure this out.

Comment: I looked in **/var/log/apache2/error.log** but nothing is logged when I try to access to the site.

Comment: Why don't you configure your apache to provide logs then.

Comment: Apache is already configured to log error, I even put it on **trace8** level 
to see if it showed something, but nothing.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your logging. trace8 will generate lots of information. 5XX errors should also be logged.